# Calling a variable from another method

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, file-io, jfilechooser

i'm quite new in eclipse and having a problems with calling variables from other methods,such as:

```
    btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

            final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            int returnVal = fc.showDialog(fc, null);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File prnfile = new File(fc.getSelectedFile().toString());

            }

        }

    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(54, 164, 89, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("print");
    btnNewButton_1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {


              File file = new File(prnfile);
                int ch;
                StringBuffer strContent = new StringBuffer("");
                FileInputStream fin = null;
                try {
                  fin = new FileInputStream(file);
                  while ((ch = fin.read()) != -1)
                    strContent.append((char) ch);
                  fin.close();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                  System.out.println(e);
                }



    });
    btnNewButton_1.setBounds(257, 164, 89, 23
```

Now,how can i  call "prnfile" from the other method?Normally i would create a public object in c# but it doesnt work in Eclipse,so i dunno where to go (being a complete noob :) )

Comment: "Call a variable"? That makes no sense. You call methods, not variables. Did you mean access the variable? Btw, this has nothing to do with Eclipse. I suggest you getting a good book about Java and start reading.

Comment: You cannot see a local variable from another method. You need to make an instance field for example. That part is not different from C# at all.

Comment: Actually, you are using two anonymous inner classes. One creates a local variable `File` and second tries to access it. This is not possible. You should create the `File` as a field in the class above the two anonymous inner classes. Only then it will be visible and accessible in both of them.

Comment: *"having a problems with calling variables from other methods"*  This sort of stuff is covered in the Java Tutorials at a very early stage.  Creating GUIs is much later.  Why don't you return to the tutorial basics and leave GUI development aside for a while?  As an aside, throwing an IDE into the mix before you understand basic OO is a recipe for disaster, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to lift out prnFile refrence so it becomes a global variable. As it is written now prnFile is only a local variable and you will not be able to see that variable in another metod and it will be collected by the GC after it's created. So take this part:

```
File prnfile = new File(fc.getSelectedFile().toString());
```

and move `File prnFile;` outside of your method. Inside the the first listener you only call `prnFile= new File(fc.getSelectedFile().toString());` and now you will be able to get the value stored inside `prnFile` from your "print listener"

Comment: Thanks all for the replies,since eclipse has no "designer.cs" sort of stuff and all gui codes are all inside the class,(and also being completely noob in eclipse or even; make that java)i just couldn't figure out where the buttons are created or the global variables are,or even where the main is :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean access your object and that has nothing to do with eclipse.

Your object prnfile is inside an anonymous class. Define your variable outside the anonymous class and you do fine.

Answer (score 1):

**prnfile** is a local variable of the **if** block of **mouseClicked**, so when control comes out of that **if** block, the **prnfile** is garbage collected and its **reference is gone**. so you cannot access that from outside that if block.